# I have an app where I am asking for input a username and password.Right now. It has been changed. Once the user clicks on login in the login menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app where I am asking for input a username and password.

Right now. It has been changed. Once the user clicks on login in the login menu.

The username should be refilled with a known username and we only ask the user to input password to improve user experience.

Could we use the exist username edit text in my layout file or i have to change to label instead of edit text? I know i can use setText() to populate the username edit text field.

The question is not about saving username (using sharedpreference). what is the best way to 
change my code to use ( either edit box or label ).

Please let me know what is the best case to avoid too much change.

Comment: use setText as you do not have to change the implementation... Also use Shared Preferences to save the userName or password whatever you feel to do so

Comment: Is it deactivate the username input field and move the cursor to password field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store the usreanme and then everytime you load the layout in your code, check your sharedPreferences and fill the username edittext using `setText`

Comment: Then, since the username edit field is pre-populated, does it look ok and the cursor will moved to password field after you launch the application.?

Comment: It won't change the focused item. You will need to do it manually.